# R: Creating an RD plot using rdplot, with the date as the running variable

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, data-visualization

I have a survey dataset that looks like this. It has the date when the survey was filled out by the respondent, and the results of the survey. I'm interested in Q2, which has answers ranging from 0 to 4:

```
| Year | Month | Date | Formatted_Date | Formatted_Date2 |   Q2   |
|------|-------|------|----------------|-----------------|--------|
| 2018 |   6   |  10  |   2018-06-10   |       17692     |    4   |
| 2018 |   6   |  12  |   2018-06-12   |       17694     |    3   | 
| 2018 |   6   |  14  |   2018-06-14   |       17696     |    2   |
| 2018 |   6   |  18  |   2018-06-18   |       17700     |    4   |
| 2018 |   6   |  21  |   2018-06-21   |       17703     |    3   |
| 2018 |   7   |  22  |   2018-07-22   |       17734     |    1   |
| 2018 |   7   |  23  |   2018-07-24   |       17736     |    1   |
```

I want to produce a regression discontinuity scatter plot that has Q2 on the y-axis, and the date on the x-axis with the cutoff at October 7th, 2018. I also would like to impose a line showing the means on either side of the cutoff. I've installed the `rddensity`, `rdrobust`, and `rddtools` packages, but I've really only tried working with the `rdplot` command.

First, I tried `rdplot(df$Q2, df$Formatted_Date, c = "2018-10-07", binselect = "qs")`, but then I got this error:

`` Error in `-.Date`(c, x_min) : can only subtract from "Date" objects ``

Then I thought maybe something is weird about working with the date class in RD plots, so I created the second date variable that you see in the table above: `df$Formatted_Date2 <- as.numeric(df$Formatted_Date)`.

I then ran this command: `rdplot(df$Q2, df$Formatted_Date2, c = 17811, binselect = "qs")`. I then got this error:

`Error in chol.default(crossprod(x)) : the leading minor of order 3 is not positive definite`.

At this point, I'm really stumped. I don't understand either error, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (I've really just started using R). Any help would be greatly appreciated, and apologies if the question isn't well-formatted!

Comment: Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, it would be useful if you could [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `dput(df)` (the data you have posted doesn't have either your desired cutoff or enough observations to even do the bin calculations)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm running into the same problem.